# Getting name of declared method

Tags: c#

```cs
Transition transition1 = new Transition("z0 -> z1",1,0, "0");
Transition transition2 = new Transition("z0 -> z2", 2,0, "1");
Transition transition3 = new Transition("z1 -> z1", 1,1, "0");
Transition transition4 = new Transition("z1 -> z2", 2,1, "1");
Transition transition5 = new Transition("z2 -> z1", 1,2,"0");
Transition transition6 = new Transition("z2 -> z3",3,2,"1");

List<Transition> transitions = new List<Transition>();
```

I want to search the list called transitions which have their currentstate variables equal to 0. And I want to get the name of the transition in the end.
Transition has variables in this order : name, nextState, currentState, triggerKey

```cs
foreach (Transition transition in transitions)
{
    int lookingForThisNumber = 0;
    if (lookingForThisNumber.Equals(transition.currentstate)) {
        Console.WriteLine(transition.GetType().FullName);
    }
}
```

After I tried this I only get the class names as output, which is not what Im really looking for.

My desired output would have have been:

transition1

transition2

Comment: I thought they would be visible and not just a link, my bad.

Comment: Thats is a variable name and that is not part of the object a variable points to. So you can't get that. For example you could have all variables from transition1  to transition6 point to the same object.  What would you expect as a result when asing for the variablename? If your Transaction should have a presentable name than give the class a property for that purpose and write the name you want to see into that property.

Comment: I don't get what your title and your body have in common, you never talk about a method in your body, but your title is asking for `name of declared method` ?!?

Comment: Note that objects don't have names. Multiple variables could refer to the same object. I suggest you add an extra parameter in the `Transition` constructor for the name that you want to print later.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of, though I wouldn't really recommend it.

It's just a random idea that poped up, this idea uses the `CallerMemberName` attribute to get the name.

In my solution I have used simple `string` members instead of your `Transition` class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //the name of the variables are irrelevant, the name that will be printed is the name of the Member in TransitionChecker
        var string1 = "Foo1";
        var string2 = "Foo2";
        var string3 = "Hello World";
        var string4 = "Foo3";
        var string5 = "Foo4";

        var transitionChecker = new TransitionChecker(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5);
        foreach (var checkedTransition in transitionChecker.CheckedTransitions)
            Console.WriteLine(checkedTransition);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class TransitionChecker
{
    private string _transition1;
    private string _transition2;
    private string _transition3;
    private string _transition4;
    private string _transition5;

    public string Transition1
    {
        get => _transition1;
        set
        {
            _transition1 = value;
            CheckTransition(_transition1);
        }
    }
    public string Transition2
    {
        get => _transition2;
        set
        {
            _transition2 = value;
            CheckTransition(_transition2);
        }
    }
    public string Transition3
    {
        get => _transition3;
        set
        {
            _transition3 = value;
            CheckTransition(_transition3);
        }
    }
    public string Transition4
    {
        get => _transition4;
        set
        {
            _transition4 = value;
            CheckTransition(_transition4);
        }
    }
    public string Transition5
    {
        get => _transition5;
        set
        {
            _transition5 = value;
            CheckTransition(_transition5);
        }
    }

    public TransitionChecker(params string[] transitions)
    {
        CheckedTransitions = new List<string>();
        Transition1 = transitions[0];
        Transition2 = transitions[1];
        Transition3 = transitions[2];
        Transition4 = transitions[3];
        Transition5 = transitions[4];
    }

    //made a list for the case that multiple transition are valid
    public List<string> CheckedTransitions { get; set; }
    private void CheckTransition(string transitionToCheck, [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = null)
    {
        if (transitionToCheck == "Hello World")
            CheckedTransitions.Add(callerMemberName);
    }
}
```

Here you can see it in action:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/FhiFey

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of Dictionary, or collection of tuples. If you must have it as different variables also, you can use such code:

```
Transition transition1 = new Transition("z0 -> z1", 1, 0, "0");
Transition transition2 = new Transition("z0 -> z2", 2, 0, "1");
Transition transition3 = new Transition("z1 -> z1", 1, 1, "0");
Transition transition4 = new Transition("z1 -> z2", 2, 1, "1");
Transition transition5 = new Transition("z2 -> z1", 1, 2, "0");
Transition transition6 = new Transition("z2 -> z3", 3, 2, "1");

var transitions = new Dictionary<string, Transition> {
  { nameof(transition1), transition1 },
  { nameof(transition2), transition2 },
  { nameof(transition3), transition3 },
  { nameof(transition4), transition4 },
  { nameof(transition5), transition5 },
  { nameof(transition6), transition6 }
};

foreach (var kv in transitions)
{
  int lookingForThisNumber = 0;

  if (lookingForThisNumber.Equals(kv.Value.currentstate))
    Console.WriteLine(kv.Key);
}
```